# Query Datatable

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable that looks like this:

```
Id Value
123 4.0
123 5.0
234 1.0
345 2.0
345 3.0
```

I want to end up with (probably a new DataTable) that contains the sum of
values grouped by Id like this:

```
Id SumOfValue
123 9.0
234 1.0
345 5.0
```

Here is my code,

```
var query = from row in dTable.AsEnumerable()
group row by row.Field<double>("ITEM_NO") into grp
orderby grp.Key
select new
{
    ITEM_NO = grp.Key,
    sum = grp.Sum(r = r.Field<double>("ITEM_STOCK"))
};
```

I am getting an error that `r is undefined`, also I am not able to add these values in a new datatable.

Does anyone know how to write this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are not specifying the operation correctly. Try this:

```
var query = from row in dTable.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<double>("ITEM_NO") into grp
                    orderby grp.Key
                    select new
                    {
                        ITEM_NO = grp.Key,
                        sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("ITEM_STOCK"))
                    };
```

The difference is `r => r.Field` instead of `r = r.Field`.

Comment: @RushabhShah You're welcome. As I said above, if this is satisfactory to you, you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, and go back to your old questions and accept an answer where satisfactory.